# Создание XML (Создать новый узел элемента)

Tags: php, xml, dom

При попытке создать XML

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$items = $dom->createElement('items');
$dom->appendChild($items);

$itemsttt = $dom->createElement('itemsttt');
$dom->appendChild($itemsttt);

$item = $dom->createElement('item');
$items->appendChild($item);

$imgs = $dom->createElement('imgs');
$item->appendChild($imgs);

$props = $dom->createElement('props');
$item->appendChild($props);

$img = $dom->createElement('img');
$imgs->appendChild($img);


$propertiesXML = $dom->createElement('properties');
$dom->appendChild($propertiesXML);

$productsXML = $dom->createElement('products');
$dom->appendChild($productsXML);

$la =  $dom->saveXML();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($la); echo "</pre>";
```

ожидаю:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<items>
  <item>
    <imgs>
      <img></imgs>
      <props></props>
  </item>
</items>
<itemsttt></itemsttt>
<properties></properties>
<products></products>
```

а получаю:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<items>
  <item>
    <imgs>
      <img></imgs>
      <props></props>
  </item>
</items>
<itemsttt>
  <properties>
    <products>
    </products>
  </properties>
</itemsttt>
```

Почему так?

Comment: А какую версию PHP используете? Просто на версии 7.4 код получился корректный. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3259b673d2f600bfd068c26a510b72e87068b434

Comment: @mepihindeveloper Спасибо за ответ, уже разобрался, при выводе в браузер, chrome форматирует элементы, если же сохранить в файл то все будет ок!

Comment: напишите тогда решение на свой вопрос, чтобы другие пользователи его видели без прочтения комментариев

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился при попытке сохранить XML в файл.